# Closest thing to variable in Excel formulas( not VBA)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have following formula

```
=MID(G34,FIND(" ",G34),FIND(" ",G34,FIND(" ",G34)+1)-FIND(" ",G34))

G34 ="begining middle end"
```

The goal of this formula is to return `"middle"` and it achieves it, but the code for it is a mess( hard to read, not DRY) all because it cannot store a variable in excel formula( in this case result of `FIND(" ",G34)`). I know that this is possible to improvise by using second cell, and it is easly done in VBA, but I intend to use this in an array formula so helper column & VBA are not possible for me.

So what are the closest possible solutions to making this formula more DRY( no more/less `FIND(" ",G34)`?

Please don't ask me what DRY stands for its a common accronym in world of programming, Thank You.

BONUS

I read [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-formulas.htm) piece and it sounds like it could be helpfull in this case but I'm confused how woudl this work in my example, if this irrelevant then forget about it other solutions will work

Comment: Well I think I understand what you are doing. How robust of an answer would you like? How many variables do you think you would have? If it is a small number then your formula way should be fine but if larger then you probably want to use VBA, and if larger yet a database.

Comment: That's a good question. The more the beter, bu tI guess I should constrain myself to just one or two. I'll just have to find out how to write complex formulas using on variable.

Comment: Then would you prefer an answer using Excel formulas or VBA?

Comment: Formulas, I know the answer in VBA, but I need avoid it

Comment: Using a name (as in the page you linked) could help. What cell should hold the mid formula? Will it always be in the same position relative to the cell with the string of words?

Comment: Minus 1 for the comment about not asking about dry.  This is an excel question and not a programming question and you are asking for help. Excel doesn't hold variables.  You can use a named range as Nick points out below or a second cell or vba those are your options.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [page you referenced about named formulas](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/named-formulas.htm), you can add your formula, and give it a name, but it will be parameterized by relative or absolute cell references. For instance, if you are in cell H34 when you create the named formula, you will only be able to use it from a cell directly to the right of the one with the text string you want to process.

For instance, I added these named formulas while G33 was selected in the worksheet:

```
firstspace: =FIND(" ", G34)
secondword: =MID(G34, firstspace+1, FIND(" ", G34, firstspace+1)-firstspace-1)
```

Now I can use =secondword in G33 and it will extract "middle" from G34.